# Android WebView shouldOverrideUrlLoading issue

Tags: android, android-webview

```
public WebView mywebview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mywebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = mywebview.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mywebview.loadUrl("http://www.infbooster.com/");
    mywebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mywebview.canGoBack()) {
        mywebview.goBack();
    } else
        super.onBackPressed();
}

public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView mywebview, String url) {

    if (!url.contains("www.infbooster.com")) {
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
        return false;

    } else {

        return true;
    }
}
```

Hello guys, I'm a newbie and need some help because I can't get this code to work right. In my website, there's a whatsapp link and it doesn't work if it's open in `webview`. So I need it to go to browser in order to open the link. Can someone please guide me or help me edit this?

Comment: have you tried my answer, if not please try. If it works then accept it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
mywebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            if(!url.contains("www.infbooster.com")) {
                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(browserIntent);
                return false;
            } 
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }

});
```